# Loading pre-set information into app?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm wanting to make a super simple app where I've got a table view and when you click on a cell you're taken to a detail page.

Normally when I've populated a tableview with data it's been from an outside source like an API and I've created my class instances as the information comes in.

If I were to create a "static" application where I've got 15 recipes that I'm wanting to display with information that I'm setting, is my code below really the way to do it?

```
var lineBreak = "\n"

class Recipie {

var ingredients = ""
var howTo = ""

init(ingredients: String, howTo:String) {
    self.ingredients = ingredients
    self.howTo = howTo
}
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var ingredientsField: UITextView!
@IBOutlet weak var howToField: UITextView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let cereal = Recipie(ingredients: "Milk\(lineBreak)Cereal\(lineBreak)Fruit", howTo: "Put it in the bowl, eat it")

    ingredientsField.text = cereal.ingredients
    howToField.text = cereal.howTo
}

}
```

From there I'd create an array of recipes and base my tableview off of the array and go through all those normal motions.

This seems hideous. I imagine on a larger if a small business asked me to create an application for them showcasing their meals/reviews that the same technique one would use to create this 10-recipe app would be used for that. I just have a hard time believing that I'm on the right track here with potentially creating 100 recipe items in my viewdidload like this. I don't see the need to use CoreData or anything with this, and I don't see how it'd change the functionality at all. This technically "works", it just seems very wrong.

Any suggestions/guidance is appreciated.

Comment: One option is to create a property list file containing the archived objects, and load from that at startup. Look up `NSKeyedUnarchiver`. You do realise with your approach, that if you add a 16th recipe, you will need to redistribute your app?

Comment: @Michael

Well I'd have to release an update right? In the same way that if I were to make an update to the plist file with the archived objects I'd have to update the app? If there's a better way to do it entirely I'm down. 

With archiving I can serialize all of this information and store it to the app to retrieve it on load from disk/nsuserdefaults but why is that even necessary? What benefit does that give over just doing it in viewDidLoad like I'm showing above.

Comment: My preference would be to have my app independent of any data that might change. For example, by loading the data from a website, rather than packaging it with the bundle. Ignoring this, there are no complelling reasons to put it in a plist rather than hardcoding as you've done, but it is perhaps a bit less hideous, as you say.